# Jython SyntaxError (from Java app)

Tags: java, syntax-error, jython

In my Java app I want to use Jython to interpret Python code.
So I initialise Jython as follows:

```
PySystemState.initialize();
PythonInterpreter jython = new PythonInterpreter();
```

Then I want to test it like this:

```
jython.eval("out = ''");
jython.eval("out += 'Test1\n'");
jython.eval("out += 'Test2\n'");
System.out.println(jython.get("out").toString());
```

However, the first eval line throws this error:

```
  File "<string>", line 1
    out = ''
       ^
SyntaxError: mismatched input '=' expecting EOF
```

When I try it with **exec** instead of **eval** I get this error:

```
  File "<string>", line 2
    '
    ^
SyntaxError: no viable alternative at character '''
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong here?

PS: I am using jython-2.5.4-rc1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to ensure you have the following

- Declare an `out` variable
- Because you're using Java, escape special characters such as `\\n`
- Use `exec` rather than `eval`

This will produce:

```
PythonInterpreter jython = new PythonInterpreter();
jython.set("out", new PyString());
jython.exec("out = ''");
jython.exec("out += 'Test1\\n'");
jython.exec("out += 'Test2\\n'");
System.out.println(jython.get("out").toString());
```

Comment: Can the jython script return a value to the enclosing java program, received as the result of the eval() method?

Answer (score 0):

You should use **exec** to execute statements. **eval** evaluates and returns a **PyObject**.

Comment: exec does not solve the problem, then I receive the following SyntaxError: no viable alternative at character '''